# Dictionary-like object in Python that allows setting arbitrary attributes

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes

What I want to do in my code:

```
myobj = <SomeBuiltinClass>()
myobj.randomattr = 1
print myobj.randomattr
...
```

I can implement a custom SomeClass that implements `__setattr__` `__getattr__`.
But I wonder if there is already a built-in Python class or simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use an empty class:

```
class A(object): pass

a = A()
a.randomattr = 1
```

Comment: Good to know. But it there already an empty class in Python library?

Comment: No, there no built-in empty class.  You can define an empty class in a single line of code, as shown.  The one-liner is as short as an `import` statement, so there's no point in looking for a built-in empty class.

Answer (score 2):

I like using the Bunch idiom for this. There are list of variations and some discussion [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use mock's:

```
from mock import Mock
myobj = Mock()
myobj.randomattr = 1
print myobj.randomattr
```

Second solution is to use namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
myobj = namedtuple('MyObject', '')
myobj.randomattr = 1
print myobj.randomattr
```