# Standard Python base class as a container for arbitrary attributes

Tags: python

Just asking this question because it seems to be a pattern that emerges quite regularly, and I'm wondering if anybody is aware of a standard library feature that supports this, or a one-liner perhaps that does something equivalent.

If I wanted to define a class for passing around data, that can contain arbitrary attributes, to be set when constructing I could do something like this:

```
>>> class Splat:
        def __init__(self, **args):
            for k, v in args:
                setattr(self, k, v)
```

and then use it like this:

```
>>> s = Splat(attr1='burp', attr2='gurt', attr3='sint')
>>> vars(s)
{'attr2': 'gurt', 'attr3': 'sint', 'attr1': 'burp'}
```

It's a pattern I've seen used in the python standard library (`ssl.wrapSocket` or something in there if memory serves) and I'd imagine it would be useful enough in general that there *could* be a commonly used python idiom or mixin that I could leverage rather than having to create my own one whenever I need it.

I know it's only a four liner to include this when I need, but in the interests of parsimony I'd like to know if there's a 0 or at least 1-liner variant I could use. Like this maybe:

```
s = TheBaseClass({'attr2': 'gurt', 'attr3': 'sint', 'attr1': 'burp'})
```

or

```
class Splat(TheBaseClass):
    pass
```

Some might be quick to jump in and say "use a dict" instead, but I'm thinking of usecases where one might wish to mock an existing object-type (duck typing) and also to infer that it is a specific "type" (like if this feature were just used as a mixin).

**Edit:** Similarly, an issue with a construction such as `s = type('Splat', (), {'attr2': 'gurt', 'attr3': 'sint', 'attr1': 'burp'})` is that I don't get to declare it, or get much in the way of type safety ...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4966509/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2350817/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2827623/3001761, ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, those links are helpful but don't really answer my question

Comment: @Kay I think that's the same as what I have at the top of my question but all one one line :)

Comment: @johnsharpe the first link you provide is "general advice" on how to implement this pattern - I am looking for an actual standard implementation

Comment: @johnsharpe the second does not provide the constructor interface I am looking for

Comment: @johnsharpe the final link is just an alternative way of doing what I'm already doing

Comment: @johnsharpe it doesn't seem as though you took my question on board at all, you just searched for random posts that just "looked like" my one.

Comment: @johnrsharpe yeah thanks, but it's not a duplicate. But anyway it looks like  kirbyfan64sos below has an answer that differs with your "opinion".

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was what the site was for. Sorry if I offended you with my mis-spelling - smack on the wrist for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit like hitting a nail with a bulldozer...but `argparse` defines a `Namespace` class that does this:

```
import argparse
print(argparse.Namespace(a=1, b=2))
```

You can always derive from it:

```
import argparse
class X(argparse.Namespace): pass
print(X(a=1, b=2))
```

However, I wouldn't really recommend that you do this, since it's kind of...icky...

At least you get `__str__` and `__repr__` for free!

Comment: @robert You mean the extra line used for importing `argparse`? :D

Comment: Sorry - actually I'm re-reading it again ... yep I think that might be what I'm looking for!

Comment: Does exactly what I want :)

Comment: I'm actually very happy with this - it's like a new toy - not at all sure why you say it's icky - looking at the source for its implementation there isn't any additional cruft beyond just what's needed .. can set default vals as class vars too. If only there was a good way to specify mandatory attributes ....

Comment: @robert that's easy enough; just subclass it and define them in `__init__`

Comment: Thanks John, was hoping for something nice & declarative like `_slots_` but that doesn't work on derived classes :( oh well there comes a point where you've got to say "good enough"!